# Migrating an env to a new python version

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-venv

I have a python app build on python 3.4

Due to an OS update I have to update this app to python 3.5.

First step I did was this to create new python version path in env

```
python3 -m venv --upgrade ENV_DIR
```

But how can I reinstall the needed packages from requirements.txt into this new 3.5 path?

When I do

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

it says all packages are already installed.

What am I doing wrong? Can someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: Easiest would be to delete your venv and just create a new one

Comment: Venvs are supposed to be cheap is discardable so rm -rf venv/ is perfectly valid suggestion. And this will test reproductibility of your environment.

Comment: As the previous other 2 comments say: delete your virtual environment and recreate one from scratch with the other Python interpreter version. Since you seem to have a `requirements.txt`, this should be a very simple operation.

Answer (score -2):

You can also use pyenv for multiple python versions.

1. Install pyenv
2. check available python versions using pyenv.

   pyenv install --list | grep " 3.[45]"
3. Install the version you want. Here you will need 3.4

   pyenv install 3.4(Any version you want)
4. Find available versions

   pyenv versions
5. Go to local folders where your project is there. Set python 3.4 version

   pyeve local 3.4
6. Check python version. It would be 3.4

   python --version
7. Create virtual Environment

   python -m venv venv
8. Install all packages using

   pip install -r requirements.txt